# how can use in RMI (Client side code) an event that define in server side code?

Tags: java, events, rmi

In RMI (client side code), how can I use an event that is defined in server side code?

For example, the following server side code defines `PropertyChangeSupport` event.

**How it can be implemented in the client side?**

```
package rmiservice.services.calculator;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class CalculatorService extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ICalculator {
private Queue<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private Integer result;
***private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);***


public CalculatorService() throws RemoteException {
    super();

}


public void start() throws Exception {
    java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    Naming.bind("CalculatorService", this);
    System.out.println("Calculator Service is Run  . . .");
}

public void stop() throws Exception {

    Naming.unbind("CalculatorService");
    UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);

    System.out.println("Calculator Service is Stop . . .");

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------ Implements ICalculator -------------

public void addNumber(Integer number) throws Exception {
    numbers.add(number);
}

public Integer getResult() throws Exception {
    return this.result;
}

public void setResult(Integer result) throws Exception {
    Integer oldResult = this.getResult();
    this.result = result;
    ***propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("result", oldResult, result);***
}

public void calculate(Operation operation) throws Exception {
    Integer _result = 0;

    if (numbers.size() < 2)
        return;

    switch (operation) {
        case Add: {
            _result = 0;
            while (numbers.size() > 0) {
                _result += numbers.poll();
            }
            break;
        }

        case Substract: {
            _result = numbers.poll();
            while (numbers.size() > 0) {
                _result -= numbers.poll();
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    this.setResult(_result);

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}

Comment: If a property value is changed on the server side how can the client was informed of the change?

Comment: Try looking for for RMI callbacks

Comment: You don't want to do this. The overhead is enormous. You need to make your remote methods much more coarse-grained, to make them worth executing when considering the network overheads and delays.

Answer (score 0):

RMI doesn't support Notification. But, you can go for JMX Beans with Event support which can be used over RMI.

Your MBean interface must extend [NotificationEmitter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationEmitter.html) for doing this.

Comment: If a property value is changed on the server side how can the client was informed of the change?

Comment: As I mentioned, you have to use Notifications. You can read more on this from Oracle Site - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/notifs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done

Sorry, my example is already made and won't fit your code exactly, but it should be quite easy to adapt

### 1. Shared code (a jar that exposes server interfaces to any client)

```
//The interface that RMI will use to pass event handlers between client and server
public interface ServerEventHandler extends Remote {

    //This is not actually required (using it for testing)
    public void setId(int id) throws RemoteException;

    //This is not actually required (using it for testing)
    public int getId() throws RemoteException;

    // Here we use String as event type.
    // Could be any number of Serializable or Remote arguments
    public void handle(String message) throws RemoteException;

}

// A simple interface that will allow us to remotely (un)register event handlers
public interface ServerObjectWithCallback extends Remote {

    public void addServerEventHandler(ServerEventHandler handler) throws RemoteException;

    public void removeServerEventHandler(ServerEventHandler handler) throws RemoteException;

}
```

### 2. Server Code (launching and interface implementation)

```
public class ServerObjectWithCallBackImpl implements ServerObjectWithCallback {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", Locale.ROOT);

    // A counter to automatically assign unique ids to new event handlers
    private int handCount = 0;
    // This will provide references to client-side event handlers and a way to
    //  access their ids with no remote call
    private HashMap<Integer, ServerEventHandler> handlers = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ServerEventHandler>();
    // A fixed pool of 10 threads for asynchronous event handling
    private ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // A simple counter that will allow printing a different message each time
    // (for the sake of this test only)
    private int eventcounter = 0;

    @Override
    public synchronized void addServerEventHandler(ServerEventHandler handler) throws RemoteException {
        // Assign a new id to handler and keep a reference to it
        handler.setId(++handCount);
        handlers.put(handCount, handler);
        System.out.println("New handler added with id " + handCount);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void removeServerEventHandler(ServerEventHandler handler) throws RemoteException {
        try {
            // Get handler id and forget about it
            int id = handler.getId();
            handlers.remove(id);
            System.out.println("Handler with id " + id + " removed");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.err.println("#Could not retrieve id for handler to unregister");
        }
        // TODO safer method "removeById" that will avoid unnecessary remote call to getId()
    }

    public synchronized void onServerEvent(Object event) {
        // This is where the remote callbacks take place
        // This method is called from server side and performs asynchronous
        //      callback on each registered client
        // TODO event should actually be of a more meaningfull type than Object
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()) + "> Firing event #" + ++eventcounter + ": " + event + " (" + handlers.size()
                + " registered handlers)");
        for (int id : handlers.keySet()) {
            try {
                ServerEventHandler handler = handlers.get(id);
                threads.execute(new EventRunnable(handler, id, event, eventcounter));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("#Could not execute async callback on handler " + id);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // A private runnable that will suit our needs to perform callbacks asynchronously
    // If we didn't, server might hang because of client behavior or missing client
    // Moreover, one client being slow would delay event dispatch to other clients
    private static class EventRunnable implements Runnable {

        private ServerEventHandler handler;
        private int handlerId;
        private Object event;
        private int eventNum;

        public EventRunnable(ServerEventHandler handler, int handlerId, Object event, int eventNum) {
            this.handler = handler;
            this.handlerId = handlerId;
            this.event = event;
            this.eventNum = eventNum;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                handler.handle("message #" + eventNum + " sent on " + sdf.format(new Date()) + " = " + event);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Better exception management : react depending on cause
                System.err.println("handler " + handlerId + " seems to have gone away: " + e.toString());
                // TODO Self-unregister handler after some unavailability time
                //  and possibly destroy client session as well
            }
        }
    }

}

public class MainCallback {
    private static ServerObjectWithCallBackImpl soc;
    private static ServerObjectWithCallback stub;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException, InterruptedException {

        Registry reg = null;
        try {
            // Startup RMI registry
            reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            System.out.println("RMI started");

            // Instantiate the RMI entry-point for the client, which will also
            //      be the object sending events
            soc = new ServerObjectWithCallBackImpl();
            stub = (ServerObjectWithCallback) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(soc, 0);
            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            reg.bind("CallbackServer", stub);
            System.out.println("ServerObjectWithCallback bound to RMI (CallbackServer). Waiting for client");

            // This will be our event object : a counter
            int count = 0;
            while (true) {
                // Wait between 1 and 5 seconds
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 4000 + 1000));
                // Fire event
                soc.onServerEvent(++count);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                // Close up registry
                UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(reg, true);
                System.out.println("RMI registry destroyed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not destroy RMI registry");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Client code (launching and handler implementation)

```
// This is our event handler implementation
// Note how it extends UnicastRemoteObject:
//  this is what allows the magic of calling client methods from server,
//  along with the fact that it implements ServerEventHandler, which is a Remote interface known from server
public class ClientSideEventHandler extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerEventHandler {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5094195049935134358L;

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", Locale.ROOT);

    // id is just a way of discriminating clients for this test
    private int id;

    public ClientSideEventHandler() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    // Make id available to server so it can number clients as it wishes
    @Override
    public int getId() throws RemoteException {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) throws RemoteException {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // This is the actual callback method
    @Override
    public void handle(String message) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()) + "> Message from server: " + message);
    }

    // Overriding toString allows testing whether the handler is a reference or
    //      a serialized copy on server side
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "[" + id + "]";
    }

}

public class MainCallback {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, RemoteException {
        // Connect to RMI registry on server
        Registry registry = null;
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1099);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting to RMI");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        ServerObjectWithCallback soc = null;
        // Create an event handler on our side
        ClientSideEventHandler handler = new ClientSideEventHandler();
        try {
            // Get RMI server entry-point from remote RMI registry
            soc = (ServerObjectWithCallback) registry.lookup("CallbackServer");
            System.out.println("CallbackServer recovered from server");
            // Register for server events
            soc.addServerEventHandler(handler);
            System.out.println("Handler registered. Waiting for events");
        } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error getting MyRemoteInterface");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Just wait indefinitely for an event to happen
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

So:

- Your server exposes its remote interfaces via a shared jar
- One of them will be implemented on server side to provide event firing (that would be your CalculatorService)
- The other one will be implemented on client side to provide event handling (that would be your PropertyChangeSupport I guess)

  - The client-side event handler also has to be a subclass of UnicastRemoteObject, so that it can be passed by proxy to the server, and that the server can remotely call methods back on it.
- Callbacks should be called asynchronously, to prevent one client from blocking a server thread and/or delaying callbacks to other clients

Comment: It doesn't have to be a subclass of `UnicastRemoteObject.` It can be exported manually.

Comment: I really don't get the downvotes : it's an actually working solution, explained in details, and no explanation given as to why it would be bad !

Answer (score -1):

I may have misunderstood the question.

But as far as I know RMI don't involve itself in the kind of event binding you are asking about.

Client will basically look up the objects registered in the RMI Registry and invoke methods in it.

You will have to implement the event handling code on your own.

If you are asking how to invoke a RMI bound object's methods you can find that in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation

Comment: If a property value is changed on the server side how can the client was informed of the change?

Comment: Only option if you are only using RMI is to constantly poll, or have another RMI Registry in the client... But that's messy...

Comment: He doesn't need a Registry in the client. The client can register a callback with the server.

Comment: With just RMI? Can point me to a resource about that?? I didn't knew that it was possible....

Comment: Never mind googled it and found it.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13211_01/wle/rmi/callbak.htm